# fsockopen works on local but not on server

Tags: php, ubuntu, http-status-code-404, wamp, fsockopen

I'm using WAMP to develop on my computer and everything works fine, but when I run my code on my server, It return's a 404. Any idea what it could be?

I'm 100% sure the file is there and exists, I can access it with my browser.

Here's my code :

```
function resetValidRecipesCache(){

require_once("diet/ValidRecipesCache.php");

$url = "http://" . $GLOBALS['domain_name']. '/services/diet/resetValidRecipesCache.php';

$parts=parse_url($url);

$fp = fsockopen($parts['host'],
    isset($parts['port'])?$parts['port']:80,
    $errno, $errstr, 1000);

$post_string = "memberId=" . getAuthMemberId();

$out = "POST ".$parts['path']." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$out.= "Host: ".$parts['host']."\r\n";
$out.= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$out.= "Content-Length: ".strlen($post_string)."\r\n";
$out.= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
if (isset($post_string)) $out.= $post_string;

fwrite($fp, $out);

fwrite($fp, $out);
while (!feof($fp)) {
    echo fgets($fp, 128);
}
fclose($fp);
exit;
}
```

Comment: Why not use cURL instead of fsockopen?

Comment: Is "your server" one you configured or at a hosting company? Some hosting companies block certain functions. Do a phpinfo() call and see if it is in the list of blocked functions.

Comment: It's an amazon server

Comment: have you tried directly accessing the url from the server? just make sure your server isn't blocking the port or the url

Comment: @basicer I tried cURL... Didn't work.

Comment: @Josh I did, I can access it with my browser.

Comment: you mean your browser of your local computer or the browser of your server?

Comment: @josh on my local computer...

Comment: you have to make sure the server, not your localhost, is not blocking the url or its port.

Comment: @Josh It's not, I can access the file (on the server) from my browser (on my computer).